# Best Practice for handling lot of images and textview in Gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

In my android mobile app, i have list of lot of (more than 200) images and textviews. For that currently i am using gridview.

But my problem is if i am request all that content at once from server then its take too much time to load and render that images and text in gridview which affect user experience.

So i thought of load only 30-40 items at once and then provide load more button at end. But it is not appropriate way to do this thing.

So can anyone please give me other alternatives to do this thing?

Comment: please search SO,there are many question already have answer to your problem

Comment: I am absolute beginner of mobile development. I tried to search for it.But didn't find any appropriate answer.

Comment: for textview no need to worry,and for images you can use this https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader  read example first

Comment: But my worry is how to handle these much of data? i mean display all at once or in parts. If not all at once then how to display other items??

Comment: can you please elaborate is your problem how to display data or how to save data. rest of the things about loading your data in parts and views handled by gridview automatically

Comment: I am not concern about saving of data but see, problem is i want more than 200 items(image + text). But at a time i cant request all items as it lead to more waiting time for users. So i am asking how can i display these items in parts(group of 30-40 items)?  I thought of displaying initial 30-40 sites then load more button at bottom but i want some good solution about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

fallow this tutorial analyze code and use it.[developer tutorial for displaying images.](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)